# Embedding a tensor of vectors into a tensor of matrices

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I want to create multiple matrices that have the property that their diagonal is zero and that are symmetric. Matrices of dimension n of this form need n*(n-1)/2 parameters to be completely specified.
These parameters shall later be learned...

In numpy I'm able to compute these by using numpy.triu_indices to get the indices of the upper triangular matrix starting at the first diagonal above the main diagonal and then fill it by the provided parameters as in the following code snippet:

```
import numpy as np

R = np.array([[1,2,1,1,2,1], [1,1,1,1,1,1]]) 

s = R.shape[1]
M = R.shape[0]

iu_r, iu_c = np.triu_indices(s,1)

Q = np.zeros((M,s,s),dtype=float)
Q[:,iu_r,iu_c] = R
Q = Q + np.transpose(Q,(0,2,1))
```

Output:

```
[[[0. 1. 2. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 2.]
 [2. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 2. 1. 0.]]

[[0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0.]]]
```

But apparently one can not directly translates this to tensorflow, as

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

M = 2
s = 4

iu_r, iu_c = np.triu_indices(s,1)

rates = tf.get_variable(shape=(M,s*(s-1)/2), name="R", dtype=float)

Q = tf.get_variable(shape=(M,s,s), dtype=float, initializer=tf.initializers.zeros, name="Q")
Q = Q[:,iu_r,iu_c].assign(rates)
```

fails with

```
TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'Pack' Op have types [int32, int64, int64] that don't all match.
```

What would be the correct way to define this tensor of matrices from a tensor of vectors in tensorflow?

**EDIT:**

My current solution is to embed using the scatter_nd function provided by tensorflow as it fits the need that no redundant variables need to be allocated as in the case of fill_triangular. Though, the indexing is not compatible with the indexes generated by numpy. Currently hardcoded the following example works:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

M = 2
s = 4

iu_r, iu_c = np.triu_indices(s,1)

rates = tf.get_variable(shape=(M,s*(s-1)/2), name="R", dtype=float)

iupper = [[[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,0,3],[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,2,3]],[[1,0,1],[1,0,2],[1,0,3],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,3]]]
Q = tf.scatter_nd(iupper,rates,shape=(M,s,s), name="rate_matrix")
```

It should be no problem to translate the indices obtained by

```
iu_r, iu_c = np.triu_indices(s,1)
```

But maybe someone has a more elegant solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need something like [convert_to_tensor](https://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor).

This function converts Python objects of various types to Tensor objects. It accepts Tensor objects, numpy arrays, Python lists, and Python scalars.

Note: TensorFlow operations automatically convert NumPy ndarrays to Tensors.

Comment: To what exactly should i apply it? As I would like to use the resulting Tensor Q in a elaborate furhter calculation and later optimize with respect to the parameters R. So I can't just convert the numpy version of Q as it would not have the gradient information with respect to R

Answer (score 0):

This part is unclear to me how it works:

```
import numpy as np

R = np.array([[1,2,1,1,2,1], [1,1,1,1,1,1]]) 

s = R.shape[1]
M = R.shape[0]

iu_r, iu_c = np.triu_indices(s,1)

Q = np.zeros((M,s,s),dtype=float)
Q[:,iu_r,iu_c] = R
Q = Q + np.transpose(Q,(0,2,1))
```

because this will fail in error.
You may use simpler code like this:

```
import numpy as np
R = [1,2,1,1,2,1]
N = 4
Q = np.zeros((N,N),dtype=float)

for i in range(0,N):
  for j in range(0,N):
    if (i<j):
      Q[i][j] = R.pop(0)
```

`Q` would be:

```
[[0. 1. 2. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

To get the symmetric Q just use this: `Q = Q + np.transpose(Q)`

Whatever zigzag you do with your rates later you can convert to Tensors like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
data_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(Q, np.float32)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()  
print(data_tf.eval())
sess.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers suggest to use the [convert_to_tensor](https://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) function, to convert your numpy array to a TensorFlow tensor.

This indeed can give you matrices with the desired property of being symmetric with a zero diagonal. However, once you start training, these properties might not hold anymore, as there is no guarantee in general that the weight updates will keep this property fixed.

If you do need to keep the matrices symmetric with a zero diagonal all along the training process, you can do the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.distributions import fill_triangular

M = 2 # batch size
s = 4 # matrix size

rates = tf.get_variable(shape=(M,s*(s+1)/2), name="R", dtype=float)

# Q will be triangular (with a non-zero diagonal!)
Q = fill_triangular(rates)

# set the diagonal of Q to zero.
Q = tf.linalg.set_diag(Q,tf.zeros((M,s)))

# make Q symmetric
Q = Q + tf.transpose(Q,[0,2,1])
```

Here is a test that verifies that the matrices hold the required properties, even after training:

```
import numpy as np

# define some arbitrary loss function
Q_target = tf.constant(np.random.normal(size=(1,s,s)).astype(np.float32))
loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(Q-Q_target)

# a single training step (which will update the matrices)
train_step =  tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# this is Q before training
print(sess.run(Q))
#[[[ 0.    -0.564  0.318 -0.446]
#  [-0.564  0.    -0.028  0.2  ]
#  [ 0.318 -0.028  0.     0.369]
#  [-0.446  0.2    0.369  0.   ]]
#
# [[ 0.     0.412  0.216  0.063]
#  [ 0.412  0.     0.221 -0.336]
#  [ 0.216  0.221  0.    -0.653]
#  [ 0.063 -0.336 -0.653  0.   ]]]


# this is Q after training
sess.run(train_step)
print(sess.run(Q))
#[[[ 0.    -0.548  0.235 -0.284]
#  [-0.548  0.    -0.055  0.074]
#  [ 0.235 -0.055  0.     0.25 ]
#  [-0.284  0.074  0.25   0.   ]]
#
# [[ 0.     0.233  0.153  0.123]
#  [ 0.233  0.     0.144 -0.354]
#  [ 0.153  0.144  0.    -0.568]
#  [ 0.123 -0.354 -0.568  0.   ]]]
```

Comment: I gave two code snippets. The first one shows how to construct the matrices. The second one demonstrates that the matrices indeed have the required property. I show that the desired property holds both and after performing a train step. To show this, I need to define the train step, which means that I should define a loss function and an optimizer. I arbitrarily chose the loss function to be the L2 distance from some other matrix, and I chose the optimizer to be gradient descent.

Comment: Thanks for writing down this solution. I already saw the function fill_triangular and but what I don't like about this approach is that one needs to generated a total of s obsolete parameters for each 1 <= i <= M which will be from the zeroed out diagonal. I edited my current solution which uses the scatter_nd function that really does the embedding and thus does not generated unneeded variables. The downside of this solution is that indices for the upper triangle without the diagonal needs to translated as the indices are not compatible with the ones generated by numpy